# Trigger to insert values in table2, when values are inserted in table1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I want to write trigger, when values are inserted in table1, same values must get added in table2.

Answer (score 2):

```
create trigger TestTrigger
on table1
after insert
as
    insert into table2
    select *
    from inserted
go
```

The assumption here is that table2 and table1 have the same amount of columns with compatible field types (that is needed when you do a "select star" with implicit fields).

If you want to put inserted values that were inserted into `table1`, you can utilize the [inserted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) table (and deleted as well for `DELETE` and `UPDATE` statements).

Comment: from inserted means? I have to write table1 am I write??

Comment: @user998533 I don't know if I understand what you're asking in your comment.  `inserted` (and `deleted`) are special tables that SQL Server manages.  It contains data from the modified table.  You can treat `inserted` as a table, which it is.  The trigger just copies the inserted data that was `INSERT`ed into Table1, and puts a copy of that data in Table2.  Make sense?

Comment: I just want to ask.... you have suggested that insert into table2
    select *
    from inserted    now i wanted to ask.. what it mean by from inserted?

Comment: @user998533: See the [documentation about SQL Server's INSERTED and DELETED "tables"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Comment: The `Inserted` pseudo table is the set of rows that were inserted in the last batch into the table the trigger is based on (here: `table1`). The trigger in SQL Server will **NOT** be called for each row - it is called **once per batch**, so when you insert 50 rows at once, you get **one call** to the trigger, and those 50 rows are available in the `Inserted` pseudo table